# Global object to apply to every page -or- Custom object

Tags: user-behavior, buttons, terminology

I have a site that allows users to create and share lists. Each page represents a different list. I'm adding a secondary list below which represents a shared or global list across all the user's pages. While this secondary list is global I want the user to have the ability to create a custom variant that is not global.

So essentially I'm maintaining a single global list which can be edited on any page, but you can disable the global aspect on a page-by-page basis.

How would you lay this out?

Here's what I've got:

[image]

Comment: One page - one list. Why not to have separate page for global list which could be customized?

Comment: It's actually pretty helpful to compile both lists in the same place because they are related. I'm also afraid users won't populate the second list if it has to be done elsewhere.

Comment: How do you manage the variants that derive from a global value? By being able to toggle this on and off, I think it would cause a few issues for the user to try and manage. Would you have a list that tracks all the variants derived from the global value?